# Fix for IE7/8 background-atachment fixed

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-8, background-image

When using background-attachment:fixed in IE7 and 8, it interprets it as scroll property.
Is there any fix for that, some JS polyfill or similar?

Answer (score 0):

Chris Coyier covers a good solution for this.
http://css-tricks.com/perfect-full-page-background-image/

Its a mix between CSS / JS fixes that all address the issue you're referring to.

Comment: Thanks, but that will not solve my problems. I need to get background-attachment:fixed behave normally in IE7/8. That link is covering resizing and cover/contain.